# Android location listener for all services

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener

I have found plenty of examples of creating a location listener where you supply a particular provider, like so:

```
LocationManager lm =
    (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
```

However, I don't need a precise location, but I'll take the best available. Is there a way to create a listener that works for the best available at the given time without creating a listener for each provider?

e.g. Use GPS if it is available, if not, Network, etc. Also, this is a widget, so I don't want to check what is available, then create a listener for that, since the widget will be up for a long duration and may live through enabling/disabling providers.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the [`PASSIVE_PROVIDER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER)?  That combined with [`getLastKnownLocation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) might get you most of the way to what you want...  You would call `getLastKnownLocation()` initially to establish a location if one was already known to the device, then the `PASSIVE_PROVIDER` would listen for updates from any location provider (i.e., location requests triggered from any other application on the device).

There would still be the possible scenario of no other application requesting location, so you'd likely want to trigger at least a single initial location fix using `GPS_PROVIDER` or `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Comment: I am actually using the `getLastKnownLocation()` function coupled with the `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` and `updatePeriodMillis` but I am trying to add the functionality to detect significant movement too. I will give it a shot.